# How to group by similar integer values in Postgres sql?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a very simple Database Table where a new entry is inserted everytime a product is scanned (RFID-Scanner).

Scans Table:

| ID (PK) | Product_ID (FK) | Created_At |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2023-01-26 10:39:00.0000 |
| 2 | 2 | 2023-01-26 10:39:02.0000 |
| 3 | 3 | 2023-01-26 10:39:04.0000 |
| 4 | 4 | 2023-01-26 10:47:00.0000 |

My goal is to cluster the product ids by the time they were scanned with a specified tolerance (in seconds), so for example for the entries in my table and a tolerance of 10 seconds, the desired result would be

| Product_IDs |
| --- |
| {1, 2, 3} |
| {4} |

My first attempt to solve the issue was something like this:

```
SELECT ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT Product_ID) FROM scans GROUP BY ROUND(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM created_at) / 10);
```

This approach works a little, but in edge cases, when for example one product is scanned at second 19 and another one at seconds 21, it wouldn't be grouped together, although it should.

What is a better, more reliable way to solve this problem?

Comment: sike! I think I just answered my own question here.

Comment: For me the question is: What if you had overlaps in your timeline: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10. Should be grouped obviously. What is with 11, 12, 13? They are more than 10 seconds away from 1 but not from 10. What is the expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume that the groups are separated if the time between to rows is more than 10 seconds. For example with test data

```
create table scans(ID int,  Product_ID int, Created_At TimeStamp);
insert into scans values
 (1,    1,cast('2023-01-26 10:39:00.000' as TimeStamp))
,(2,    2,cast('2023-01-26 10:39:02.000' as TimeStamp))
,(3,    3,cast('2023-01-26 10:39:11.000' as TimeStamp))
,(4,    4,cast('2023-01-26 10:47:00.000' as TimeStamp))
;
```

Calculate time difference between current row and preceding. When difference greater than '10 second' - thats new group of scans starts.

```
with ScansDif as(
  select * 
    ,Created_At-lag(Created_At,1,Created_At)over(order by Created_At) dif
  from scans
)
,ScansGroup as(
  select * 
     ,sum(case when dif>cast('10'||' second' as interval) then 1 else 0 end)
          over(order by Created_At rows unbounded preceding) grN
  from ScansDif
)
SELECT ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT Product_ID) 
FROM ScansGroup 
GROUP BY grn
```

Group numbers

| id | product_id | created_at | dif | grn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2023-01-26 10:39:00 | 00:00:00 | 0 |
| 2 | 2 | 2023-01-26 10:39:02 | 00:00:02 | 0 |
| 3 | 3 | 2023-01-26 10:39:11 | 00:00:09 | 0 |
| 4 | 4 | 2023-01-26 10:47:00 | 00:07:56 | 1 |

Time difference between first and last row of group 0 is 00:11.
Result

| array_agg |
| --- |
| {1,2,3} |
| {4} |

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/V7s5b5u_)